# Set http response Content-Type to "xml" in python

Tags: python, xml, mod-python

How do I display on an html page an xml?

how can I set in python text/html?

I'm writing in the html as:

```
response.out.write
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your using `mod_python`:

```
response.content_type = "text/xml"
```

Or:

```
response.content_type = "text/html"
```

http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-mprequest-mem.html

> `content_type`
>
> String. The content type. Mod_python maintains an
>   internal flag (req._content_type_set) to keep track of whether
>   content_type was set manually from within Python. The publisher
>   handler uses this flag in the following way: when content_type isn't
>   explicitly set, it attempts to guess the content type by examining the
>   first few bytes of the output.

---

If you just want to have pretty xml output in a text file, use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) `prettify()` on the xml.

Comment: this worked, before I was using response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml" and it didn't work. Is there a way to get it to print the tags in python like this example in php? http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_server.asp

Comment: The xml is rendered by the web browser.  Right click and "view source" to see the actual xml.

Comment: There is probably a xml/meta/some sort of tag though that would tell the browser not to render the xml, not sure though, ill have to look into it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, in the view source i see the xml with tags, but not on the browser

Comment: The content type, i am thinking, is actually what is telling the browser to render it as xml.  If you just set content_type = "text" it may show the tags as it does when you view source.